# Applying scaleX/scaleY to a movie clip results in cropped image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

So I'm using a swc inside Flash Builder that contains a movie clip.

The problem I have is that I need to scale this movie clip with scaleX and scaleY. This part works fine if I trace the width/height values of the object, but when you actually see the object, it looks as it has been cropped instead of resized.

For example, if I apply a scale factor of 0.5, then I will only see a fourth of the original image, which would be the upper left corner.

The symbol being used and exported to the swc consists of a movie clip that contains another movie clip and this second movie clip contains a shape. Not sure, if this can be affecting the scaling somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're sure there's no code inside the movieclip you're placing?  it sounds like it's updating its self somehow...

Comment: It doesn't have any code inside of it. I actually replaced everything inside the main symbol with just a flat image, to test if it would work and it's still getting cropped. No idea why.

Comment: that's bizarre and shouldn't be happening... can you post your project zipped somewhere (ideally just the part that's broken)?  I'll be back on again in 8-or-so hours and am interested to see what the problem is.

Comment: I read your problem and as per fundamental should work. But as per your post and comment..there is some issue. can you send your code to me on my email? I will check and come with some solutions. my email address is mrugeshapatel@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you, both. I've been kinda busy, but I'll try to send you the code in a few hours. I really appreciate your interest in helping me.

Comment: Is there any masking used in a MovieClip or SWC?

Comment: Sounds like you're scaling the mask. Try scaling the parent of the object you are currently scaling instead.

Comment: did you try setting the scale factor to 2 instead of 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

Your movieClip content origin point is not 0,0.
When you are scaling a MovieClip (Or any other DisplayObject) you are scaling it in relation to its origin.

Let's say that your MovieClip content is a black rectangle in the size of 200x200, but the rectangle was drawn from 100, 100. The MovieClip was probably placed at -100,-100 to "sit" on the origin.
So now, when you scale it to 0.5, you will see only the bottom right...

All you have to do it draw the content from 0,0. and place the movieClip on 0,0 and now when you scale it, it will scale from the top-left corner.

This might help: http://flashexplained.com/basics/understanding-how-the-coordinate-system-in-flash-works/